# Size of our Exchange backups : Exchange 2010 archive

Tags: exchange-server

We have recently migrated our backups from Exchange management console Networker to DELL Appassure but a problem we are facing is the size of our Exchange backups & we think this is down to the amount of transaction logs being produced daily & therefore backed up.
Mail store logs are not a concern but we are having lots of transaction logs for our Microsoft exchange2010 archive.  To give some ideas of size, we have 400 mailboxes  & the mail store is 110GB and our archive store is 690 GB.  The logs get reduced at about 3AM (its now 6PM) and we have 2.8GB wroth of mail store logs and 50GB of archive logs!  We have about 110 users having archives.  We can produce around 110GB of transaction logs per day and about 85% of that is from the archive.

Is this the type of log creation scale - we should expect from Exchange 2010 archive?

Comment: Just a tip--this may belong in ServerFault.

Comment: Vishal, No it don't belong to ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I faced the similar situation a few months ago. I had a DPT (Default Policy Tag) set along with RPT tag that were incompatible with each other. In fact, you cannot have an RPT that performs the same thing as the DPT even if the time period is dissimilar. So, in my case, DPT used to move everything to the archive after 2 years. Then, RPT tag moved the Sent Items to the archive after every 3 months. These two tags were performing the same thing and Microsoft Exchange server does not allow it. As a  matter  of fact, if you attempt to create RPT tag after  enabling the DPT, then Exchange  Management Console will not allow you to do it. So, at the same time both were running together in my case, which resulted in the huge amount of transaction logs. But once we removed the Sent Items RPT Tag, right away the log generation stopped.

If both RPT and DPT are performing different actions, then there will be no problem.

Comment: Thanks Eric , with your steps I m able to resolve my issue. Thanks for your time and solving my query.